# Unable to launch Chrome on Mac OSX using Selenium grid

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome, selenium, grid

I am trying to perform automation testing using Selenium & Java on MAC Sierra but I keep getting the following error when I run the `testng.xml`:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new
>   session cannot find : Capabilities [{browserName=chrome,
>   chromeOptions={args=[--start-maximized, --disable-web-security],
>   extensions=[], prefs={credentials_enable_service=false,
>   profile.password_manager_enabled=false}}, version=, platform=macOS
>   10.12}] Command duration or timeout: 61 milliseconds

The hub & node are running on the same Mac computer. Here is the command line to launch node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Here is the sample code which is running absolutely fine on Windows 10:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/varun/webautomation/Executables/chromedriver");
capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
getPlatformCapabilities(platform);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteAddress), capabilities);
```

Can anyone please help me out? I have searched posts but cannot seem to find the solution. The last line in the terminal window running the hub is:

**Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, chromeOptions={args=[--start-maximized, --disable-web-security], extensions=[], prefs={credentials_enable_service=false, profile.password_manager_enabled=false}}, version=, platform=macOS 10.12}]**

Answer (score 0):

By default, selenium grid uses port 4444 for hub and port 5555 for node. It may be the port forwarding issue. Is you system allows port 4444 and 5555. If it it is not enabled add it in your firewall for TCP/IP and UDP protocols. Both ports are enabled by default in Windows. So that you are not getting any issues there.

Comment: I am in an office environment so I have asked the network team to check the ports. I also tried using a Windows node with the Mac computer as the hub again but the same error appears. The node gets registered when its launched but when the test runs, the Mac computer is unable to find the node & marks it as down. Mac's firewall is off though.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a non-perfect solutuion which is working for now. I had to remove the code related to passing arguments & chrome options which was the source of the problem as this is not working on Mac OSX. My final code was:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/varun/webautomation/Executables/chromedriver");
capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteAddress), capabilities);
```